# What do I risk if I name my game the same as another company?

Tags: marketing

I came up with the best title for my game - a title that is catchy and also indicative of the gameplay, plus there isn't any other game on the market with a similar name. But after a Google search, I found a company in another country using the same name.

To put my situation better in context, imagine a game like Minecraft being in development, only to find out that there's another company called something like Minecraft Studios in a far-off country dealing with digital graphics and art for media (including games).

*Aside from the legal aspect of it* (lawsuits, cease-and-desists, etc.), what disadvantages would there be to have my game named the same as a company dealing in a similar field?

Comment: Just use the name and after that you will see if you will have to change the name or not. Just try it out. Probably you wont have any problems

Comment: I'm really tempted to do that but still not sure if I'm able to take the risk of getting sued or something...I am just a student attempting to make my first game, after all, and I have very much to lose I do something wrong. Still, I'll probably just go along with it if I feel brave enough someday XD Thank you so much for answering! 

Comment: You really need a legal professional who is experienced with trademark law to advise you on what you do or do not have to do. If it was me? I'd change it to avoid potential for trouble, but I'm not a legal professional and I don't know if that's something I would need to do.

Comment: "Not sure if I'm able to take the risk of getting sued" — nothing we can say here will make that risk go away. If you want protection against legal action, talk to a lawyer, not a game developer. From a game standpoint though, even ignoring the legal side, consider that you'll be competing with this other company for search hits. This could make it harder to get players into your game.

Comment: @Maximus Minimus, I agree that consulting a lawyer is always the best choice...I'm just hoping if anyone who had similar experiences in the past could help. As changing my game's name is the safest and cheapest option by far, I'm willing to pick a weaker name if I keep meeting dead ends. Thank you for replying!

Comment: @DMGregory, I do know that the risk is there, but I'm wondering if anyone can share similar experiences to help me gauge if it really is a risk I can take. Consulting a lawyer is something I would do if there's still hope for my title...if not, I figure I'm better off changing it. As for search hits, I think competition will be ok as the names are used for different audiences--one for gamers and one for potential devs. Thank you for your advice!

Comment: There is another Minecraft, Minecraft consulting, check out Minecraft.com (it was registered in '03). But 100% do get a lawyer and reconsider

Comment: I reworded and reopened the question. Although it is still a bit broad, I think if it had popped up in this state, I would not have closed it right away. (Keep in mind that users can still answer on _other aspects_ of the issue, as long as they answer the question; this makes the current answer an acceptable one, per our standards.)

Comment: @Vaillancourt I agree with that decision, this question is much more on-topic after edit. And thank you for tweaking my answer as well :)

Answer (score 4):

The biggest risk you face is a customer confusion issue. If your game has the same identifying name as a company, anybody who tries to search for your game will probably get the company in their search results instead, which lessens the searchability of your game - especially if you are a small indie developer and the game isn't popular yet.

---

That being said, [Spooky's House of Jumpscares was forced to rename itself to Spooky's Jump Scare Mansion after a lawsuit from a company called Spooky House Studios.](https://gameranx.com/updates/id/54623/article/spookys-house-of-jump-scares-renamed-to-spookys-jump-scare-mansion/) So you could absolutely have a lawsuit brought against you even if it's legally spurious to do so, hence why I recommend talking to a lawyer if you have genuine concerns.

Comment: Thank you for your advice and the link. It definitely helped me bring things into perspective! 

Comment: Or talk to the company first? They could very well say "yeah, sure, if anything it will benefit us".